# C# code to get list item to send to email?

Tags: c#, list, email, sharepoint

I can send emails by using this:

```
mail.To.Add("sample@test.com");
```

However, I'd like to send out emails by getting it from a SharePoint list, so far I have this.

```
List<string> to = new List<string> {"test@sample.com"};

foreach(string address in to)
{
    mail.To.Add("to");
}
```

I'm getting an error.

```
The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
```

Comment: is this a typo?   try mail.To.Add(address);   maybe you should get into some c# basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
List<string> to = new List<string> {"test@sample.com"};

    foreach(string address in to)
    {
        mail.To.Add(address);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the string "To" to the mail, for all the elements of the List.
Instead of this you should add the address value.